# Using Veeva Vault, how do I connect to a Related Shared Resource?

Tags: css, html, salesforce

I'm using Veeva Vault for a project, and I'm unable to get the Related Shared Resource option to work. I'm basically uploading an HTML5 page, and I want to link to a global css file.

This is the Help Guide - http://vaulthelp2.vod309.com/wordpress/applications/promotional-materials-edition/using-clm-integration/

In Veeva, I have a binder presenation, which houses all of my key messages. The key message structure looks like this:

```
myfilename.zip
myfilename
    myfilename.html
    myfilename-full.jpg
    myfilename-thumb.jpg
    assets
       css
       img
       js
```

I used the Veeva CRM App to get them to display on the iPad. This works fine. I can see my presentation and all of the slides (key messages).

I created a shared folder that looks like this:

```
[shared]
    mysharedname.zip
    mysharedname
        mysharedname-full.jpg
        mysharedname-thumb.jpg
        css
        img
        js
```

The shared folder is created by Veeva (according to this - https://crmhelp.veeva.com/doc/Content/Print-only_topics/CLM%20Content%20Creation%20Guide.pdf - pg. 70). In Veeva, I added the files as a slide using these options:

```
Name
Type (Slide)
Country
CLM Properties (Yes)
Product
Renditions
```

The link to the shared folder in my HTML5 file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/main.css">
```

Once uploaded, I went to the myfilename slide, and checked the **Related Shared Resource** option, and selected the *mysharedname* slide. I performed a Force Full Refresh, and synced. The class I set in the *mysharedname/css* file does not display.

I've tried variations with folder names, added the shared file to the Binder, changed the path of the link to *../shared/mysharedname/css/main.css*, etc. with no success.

I've used test.salesforce.com in the past to upload key messages and set shared files. However, I'm unfamiliar with how that's accomplished using Veeva Vault. I'm certain I'm either naming the files incorrectly, or not entering the key message correctly.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were two issues. For some unknown reason, the file didn't post properly. Tech support couldn't determine the reason, but suggesting creating a new shared file - which worked!

Also, in posting the new shared file, I noticed the Distribution Package (zip file) keep "disappearing" in the upload process. So, I just re-attached it (in Veeva Vault - INFORMATION > Renditions).

Oh, and the shared file should be outside of the binder.

Answer (score -1):

To link a shared resource in veeva vault please follow the rules for example

./shared/css/base.css

Shared zip structure should be

shared.zip 
 css
base.css
[shared_folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3yc.jpg)

and you need to add the shared resource to the main file perimeter
[parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ugAB.jpg)